# HTML5 & CSS3 Web App

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I want to create an APP for android using HTML5 & CSS3. I just started to learn HTML5 and CSS3. I downloaded the following mobile template :

http://themeforest.net/item/faller-mobile-retina-html5-css3-with-webapp/6087395

So now I have all the required files(.html,.css,.javascript files) ready.
Now If I want to directly create an app out of it, what do I do ?
Which software do I need to download to convert this into an .apk file for android?
Please explain in simple words :)

Answer (score 2):

As a beginning point of reference google for "phonegap" this is a relatively quick and easy way to begin creating applications for Android,IOS and windows mobile. If you want to get more serious though you will need to look into downloading and learning the "Software Development Kits" for each platform you are interested in.

There are also other tools out there and might be worth your while doing a search for tools like "mosync" and "Xamarin".

Good luck it can sometimes seem a maze of information but should not take too long to get the basics.

Comment: The SDK isn't gonna help much if you specifically want to create hybrid apps. Phoengap is probably the best way to start, though, so +1. However, I'm not sure a beginner to web development in general should start with making hybrid apps. But that's just an opinion.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've been trying to read about phonegap. So after I install phonegap, will I be able to convert the above template into a complete android apk file ? Also, I have Adobe Dreamweaver CC 13.1 which says it can convert a html5 to android apk. Can I use that too ?

Comment: Not sure about using Dreamweaver to be honest I just dabbled with phonegap and phonegap build online hope you manage to get right otherwise post more questions lots of very knowledgeable people on stackoverflow sure some-one will be able to give you some more pointers. Good luck.